# Some wrong data in a memory layout (arm assembly stm32)

Tags: assembly, stm32, cortex-m

I rewrite a code from the book and burn it to stm32f103c8t6 (bluepill)

```
    EXPORT __main
    AREA PROG_2_2, CODE, READONLY
__main
    LDR R2, =OUR_FIXED_DATA
    LDRB R0, [R2]
    ADD R1, R1, R0
HERE B HERE
OUR_FIXED_DATA
    DCB 0x55, 0x33, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    DCD 0x23222120, 0x30
    DCW 0x4540, 0x50
    END
```

But during the debug I got different values

I should get the following values in the memory (from book):

[55 33 01 02 03 04 05 06 20 21 22 23 30 00 00 00 40 45 50 00 FF FF FF FF FF .....]

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8E5Q.png)

This I got:

[55 33 01 02 03 04 05 06 20 21 22 23 30 00 00 00 40 45 50 00 D0 02 00 08 FF FF FF FF .....]

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i3ZD.png)

Why did I get 4 last bits ? (I should not write D0 02 00 08 in memory, I didn't specify it in my code)

**Udpate:** *(list of files)*
[Project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCEqG.png)

This files I just chosen for my microcontroller (I just followed step-by-step to this pdf:

https://nicerland.com/eduFiles/STM32F103/Tutorials/STM32_Asm_prog_in_Keil.pdf

This is a link that was written in a book, like an additional feature.

Comment: You show just one assembly file. The hex lines come from anywhere, I assume after linking. What other object files has been used? Probably, the linker adds some standard file.

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: I added CMSIS files for the MCU

Comment: @harper, I also wrote all data

Comment: Not sure without more information but it looks like the address of `OUR_FIXED_DATA` is getting appended to the end of the data, which might be coming from `LDR R2, =OUR_FIXED_DATA` since that instruction loads data from an offset and not straight from the instruction word.

Comment: Can you tell us which book you are using for this?

Comment: neither of those look correct unless whatever assembly language you are using thinks a word for arm is 16 bit, which it is not.

Comment: those extra bytes come from some other source in the link, you have not shown everything, please provide a complete example.

Comment: and you need to specify the assembly language (specific to the tool not the target, so specify the tool, version, command line options used).

Comment: @ElliotAlderson this one: The STM32F103 Arm Microcontroller and Embedded Systems: Using Assembly and C

Comment: @old_timer I added  details, please look at it :)

Comment: arm does not have direct 32 bit load so it an address of `OUR_FIXED_DATA`. Value looks reasonable.